# Process.StandardOutput stream to events

Tags: c#

This is really a streams question, but I'm asking specifically to solve my current problem with processes.

System.Diagnostics.Process exposes StandardOutput as a stream. I want to listen to this stream and process its output line by line. Obviously there's no direct correlation between input and output, but let's add the slightly artificial requirement that we can process output "by line".

So most examples of using it look like this:

```
using (Process process = Process.Start(start))
{
    //
    // Read in all the text from the process with the StreamReader.
    //
    using (StreamReader reader = process.StandardOutput)
    {
    string result = reader.ReadToEnd();
    Console.Write(result);
    }
}
```

Which is of no use as it isn't event driven and assumes the process lives just long enough to return some output. By event driven, it doesn't have to be an event. A lambda, callback, event, whatever, I just want notification when a whole line is output and I want to be able to shutdown cleanly when I finish with the process.

Essentially I'm asking are streams poll only.

Thanks

Comment: Have you looked at `Process.OutputDataReceived`?

Comment: Hi Jon, just popped back to add a comment to say I've just found OutputdataReceived. Is there an answer to processing a long lived intermittantly spewy stream that doesn't require there to be a helpful notifying ... notifier?

Comment: Not sure what you mean, to be honest. It's not clear what you're looking for beyond OutputDataReceived. Note that you could just put your loop into a separate thread...

Comment: It does sound like you want to essentially rewrite `OutputDataReceived`.  Perhaps [this is the place to start](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/services/monitoring/system/diagnosticts/Process.cs,2553).

Comment: I'll add a new question I think which avoids all talk of Process. Although if I guess it boils down to "do you have to poll a stream" to find out if it contains data? I think the answer is yes. Probably sounds obvious, but I rarely need to deal directly with long lived streams.

Comment: BTW Jon, if you could pop your comment in an answer, I'll re-edit the question to be more Process specific as your comment answers the actual question properly.

Comment: What type of process are you starting? Is it a command prompt, or another application written by you? I recently had to start a command prompt and read from it's output, so I choose to write all the output to a file ( echo test > file.txt ) then read from the file once the process reported it had exited. Maybe you can use a mixed approach with this?

Comment: Actually  João that's a good plan I think anyway. It avoids the vagueries of console redirection and gives "another" written log of what's going down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can receive data using the `Process.OutputDataReceived` event. It can be tricky to use. Search Stack Overflow for it and you'll find a few synchronization issues and pitfalls.

In general you never need to poll a stream for data. In fact there is no way to poll as far as I'm aware. You either read synchronously or asynchronously. Your call will only complete when there is data or the stream is depleted.

In the async case you can view the callback you receive as an event. So just call `BeginReadLine` and that's your event. Or do it with tasks.